# error regarding linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/zalak.patel/Projects/iOS/FeedAPuppy/Code/iOS/Library/lb_ios_sdk_v4.6/AppFireworks'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/zalak.patel/Projects/iOS/FeedAPuppy/Code/iOS/Library/lb_ios_sdk_v4.6'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/zalak.patel/Projects/iOS/FeedAPuppy/Code/iOS/Library/LeadBolt'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK/lb_ios_sdk_v4.6/AppFireworks'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK/lb_ios_sdk_v4.6'

ld: library not found for -lAppTracker

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What should i do to solve this error?
i have deleted folder lb_ios_sdk_v4.6 and placed content of this folder in another folder named LeadBolt

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue before. Goto the build settings page of your project. Search for Library Search Paths and remove all of the paths. Once that is done remove the libAppTracker.a from the frameworks section on the General screen of your project then add it back in. After all of that perform a clean and then build. That is what continues to work for me to solve this issue.